# WinGW g++ put_money iomanip gives unexpected result

Tags: g++, iomanip

I'm trying to format currency, using the bellow code as a test.

```
long double mon = 1234567.45; // or std::string mon = "123.45";
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
std::cout << "normal:   " << mon << std::endl;
std::cout << "formated: " << std::showbase << std::put_money(mon*100) << std::endl;
```

But I get an unexpected result.

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O1 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o tst.o tst.cpp
g++ -o tst tst.o

normal:   -2.64326e-199
formated: 526296518301961010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I'm using g++ version 4.8.1, on Win10

On my Ubuntu machine, using  version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04).
I get the following correct result.

```
normal:   1,12346e+06
formated: € 1 123 456,45
```

What is going on??

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found out this a is bug with MinGW g++ 4.8.1.
This version does not handle the long double type verry well.

[Long Double Output Bug In MinGW](http://www.diusrex.com/2015/05/long-double-bug-in-mingw/)